# Pdf-latex & tikz-feynman

Tags: tikz-feynman

Recently I have known how to use tikz-feynman with pdf-latex but I missunderstand one moment. I have used:

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}             %% Load the `external` library
\immediate\write18{mkdir -p pgf-img}  %% Create `pgf-img` directory
\tikzexternalize[                     %% Activate externalization
  prefix=pgf-img/,                    %% Avoid cluttering the directory
  system call={                       %% Use lualatex in system call
    lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname="\image" "\texsource"
  },
]
```

but, unfortunately, compilation produces a lot of errors. As I understand, these errors doesn't give any problems, but I would like to clarify it.

For instance, I will try to give a sample of code which works but produces errors.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}             %% Load the `external` library
\immediate\write18{mkdir -p pgf-img}  %% Create `pgf-img` directory
\tikzexternalize[                     %% Activate externalization
  prefix=pgf-img/,                    %% Avoid cluttering the directory
  system call={                       %% Use lualatex in system call
    lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname="\image" "\texsource"
  },
]
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax]
\begin{feynman}
    \vertex (v1);
    \vertex[right=0.7cm of v1] (v2);
    \vertex[above right=0.7cm of v2] (v3);
    \vertex[below right=0.7cm of v2] (v4);
    \diagram*{(v1)--[boson](v2),(v2)--[fermion](v3),(v4)--[fermion](v2)};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The first appeared error is[image]

Comment: errors always give you problems, never ignore them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using overleaf I do not know, sorry.

But the error message is very clear for me: The issue here is that you want to run `\immediate\write18{mkdir -p pgf-img}`.

With my current MiKTeX I have to add the command option `-shell-escape` to the call of `lualatex.exe` to enable LuaLaTeX to start an extern run ...

Please ask the support of overleaf how to do that with overleaf (if it is possible there) ...

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been solved in the very strange way.

I change compiler to LuaLaTeX and it still gives errors. Then I change compiler one more time to pdf-LaTeX and now it works without errors.